# Java error: int cannot be dereferenced error

Tags: java

I have an array of superclass car. There are two types of objects in this array - NewCar object and UsedCar object. Each car object has int price. I want to print a list of car objects below a certain price.

```
public String printAllCarsWithSellingPriceBelow(int p){
 String s = "";
    for (int i; i < CAR_COUNTER; i++) {
        //s += cars[i].toString();
        s += cars[i].printThis(i) + "\n";
        if ( i.getPrice < p){
        int h = i.getPrice;
        s += cars[h].printThis(h) + "\n";            }
    }
    return s;
```

I keep getting this error:

TestDealer.java:125: error: int cannot be dereferenced

```
        if ( i.getPrice < p){

              ^
```

TestDealer.java:126: error: int cannot be dereferenced

```
        int h = i.getPrice;

                 ^
```

2 errors

in this code:

```
if ( i.getPrice < p){
            int h = i.getPrice;
            s += cars[h].printThis(h) + "\n";            }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is type of `i`? Something tells me it is `int`. In that case what are you trying to do with `i.getPrice`?

Comment: What do you expect that code to do? Why?

Comment: What is `i` and why do you call a method without `()` on `i`? Seems `i` is an integer here.

Comment: What is getPrice supposed to be? A function? A field?

Comment: I'm guessing `i` is an `int`.

Comment: You seem to know that to get car at position `i` from array of cars you need to use `cars[i]`. When you already have such car you can invoke `getPrice` method on it like `cars[i].getPrice()` - remember that methods always have `(` `)` after them for method arguments, in case of no arguments just write `()`.

Answer (score 2):

The `i` variable is of type int.

Since type `int` is a primitive, no methods nor fields can be referenced from the variable. ONLY `objects` can have methods and fields.

One way to fix it is just use the value of `i`

```
if( i > p){
    int h = i;
    ....
```